# Enter a constant item in a column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, power-automate, flow

I have a list with a `username` column and I would like to fill the entire column with a constant `username` (associated with a Microsoft account).

Right now the list has `4854` items. So, for these `4854` items the username would be `a` (`a` being the constant username in this case). For item `4855` and so on, a username can be unique like `b`, `c`, `d` and etc.

How can I do this without having to manually enter the same username for the entire column?

Comment: How many items are currently in list? Do you want to set the default / constant value for new items created in future as well or for existing items in list only?

Comment: For existing items only.

Comment: @GaneshSanap, thumbs up for the great question btw.

Comment: You can use PowerShell or Power Automate flow to read and update all items.

Comment: @GaneshSanap thank you, can you please share a workflow for either or both in an answer? In case of `PowerAutomate` what functions will I have to use in each step? Btw I have never used `Powershell` before but I might learn about it from the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Power automate flow to get all items from SharePoint list and update those using "Update item" action. You can use flow like below:

[image]

As you have less than 5000 items, you can fetch those using "Top Count" in Get items action. If you want to fetch more than 5000 items, you can enable pagination from "Get items" action settings:

1. Click on ellipses (...) on "Get items" action and select "Settings"
2. Enable Pagination, enter the number of items you want to fetch and click "Done"

[image]

---

**Additional information**:

If you have less number of items in list, you can also use "Edit in grid view" option from SharePoint list to update multiple items at a time.

Comment: In my case since I have a `username` column, `Update item` is showing `Username Claims`, `Username DisplayName`, `Username Department`, `Username email`, `Username picture`, `Username JobTitle`. Out of these, which one should I select for `Title`, maybe `Username DisplayName`, because I am just entering the `username` not the whole email address? So, based on your answer, the username would be `abc`.

Comment: Oh never mind, I think I do need to select `title` for `Title` and put the `value` in `Username claims`.

Comment: This question might sound subjective, but how long should the flow take to complete? The flow is still running for more than an hour now. When I refresh the list, the `Username` column still appears empty.

Comment: I think it has to do with the `manual trigger`, how can I activate/trigger it to run the flow? And for some reason I am not seeing the `flow` button in the pane on top of a list in `modern view`.

Comment: From the flow editor, click on "Test" from top right corner then select "Manually" > "Run flow" > "Done"

Comment: For Title column, use same Title column from get items action. For username claims, you have to pass the valid email address.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you can't set a default value on People and Group fields, either by the UI, PowerShell, or code.

The best alternative I can think of is to set the column value using a Power Automate flow using the When an item is created trigger. You can check to see if there is a value for the column, and if there isn't you can set the default value.

Comment: It's not a default value per say. Let's say right now the list has `100` items. So, for these `100` items the username would be `a`. For item `101` and so on, a username can be unique like `b`, `c`, `d` and etc.