# Get Items returns no data

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, odata

I just had a question about an issue I am facing:

I am attempting to return some items from a SharePoint list for a flow on Power Automate. Currently, I'm attempting to retrieve the data for a specific date, and the data amount is about 4000 items for that date. The full list has maybe about 30-40 thousand items in the list. I am using an ODATA filter query in the Get items connection that filters by date, so for this specific day, there are about 4000 items to retrieve.

However, the get items returns no data in its output. I have checked the SharePoint list to confirm data exists for this date, and it does. So I was wondering what the issue may be here. Thanks.

The ODATA filter query works with other dates I input, just some dates it doesn't work with. Another observation is that the ODATA filter query seems to work when the date has around 100 items, but not when it has about 4000 items. Does that play a role? And if it does, what is a possible workaround for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

1. Add indexing for this date column: [Add an index to a list or library column](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-index-to-a-list-or-library-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0)
2. Add **Top Count** to 5000 in get items action:

   [image]
3. Enable pagination from get items action settings. You can set pagination limit up to 100000. Refer for detailed steps: [Enter a constant item in a column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304415/enter-a-constant-item-in-a-column/304418#304418)

   [image]