# Automatically delete the selective items from columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column, delete

I have a list which I use as a means for people to answer questions that I ask (think of an audit).

I have 87 rows and the first column is the criteria question which I have already filled. Then the user has to fill several other fields for those questions.

I want to delete the fields that the user has filled but always leave the questions intact (in order to use the same list in 3 months' time to perform the same audit again).

Could someone give me an idea how to do it?

Comment: You want to do it manually or using scheduled power automate flow which will run every 3 months?

Comment: Check my answer given here for grid view approach: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292845/how-do-we-vertically-delete-values-from-a-single-column/292848#292848 and here for Power automate approach (here I am adding constant value for all columns, you can adjust it as per your requirements): https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304415/enter-a-constant-item-in-a-column/304418#304418. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

A way to directly do it via SharePoint Online will be to use the **editable Grid View**. Steps below.

Alternatively, if this is too tedious, you can explore using **Power Automate** flow to clear out all values other than the first column.

1. Choose **'Edit in grid view'**  in the menu bar

[image]

2. The list now changes into an *editable Grid View*

[image]

3. Assuming you want to clear out all values in **Answer A**, delete the first cell in **Answer A**
   [image]
4. Click the **bottom right corner of the first cell** and **drag downwards**. All the values in the cells below will then be cleared.

[image]
[image]